# JQuery Button enable and disable CSS functionality upon Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the LeaderboardButton upon clicking change its DIV to have bottom border radius. (It does that). But how can I upon clicking again, have it reset to having no border radius. Essentially. You click once, border radius. Click again, no border radius. Click again, border radius come back. Click again and border radius leave. etc. etc.
Essentially and ON/OFF of CSS radius functions.

Here's my code below.

```
$('#left-container').click(function(){
    $('#leaderboard').slideToggle( "slow", function(){  
        $('#leadeboardButton').css({borderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
             borderTopRightRadius: 0, 
             borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, 
             borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
             WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
             WebkitBorderTopRightRadius: 0, 
             WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius: 10, 
             WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius: 10, 
             MozBorderRadius: 10 
        }), function(){
$('#leadeboardButton').css({borderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
     borderTopRightRadius: 0, 
     borderBottomLeftRadius: 0, 
     borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
     WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
     WebkitBorderTopRightRadius: 0, 
     WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius: 0, 
     WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius: 0, 
     MozBorderRadius: 0
     });
                    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move your border styling into your css. Make sure you have one class for the border (we'll call it border). Then your javascript would get much simpler.

```
$("#leftcontainer").click(function() {
    if ($("#leftcontainer").hasClass("border")) {
        $("#leftcontainer").removeClass("border");    
    } else {
        $("#leftcontainer").addClass("border");
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrXCU/2/

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible if you create two CSS classes, where both of the css classes will have different CSS classes.
after every click on button, check the existing class associated with the button and change the class .

you can use the jquery method [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)  for toggling between two classes.